# Overriding the native PHP function file_get_contents to add profiling/logging

Tags: php, profiler

I'd like to wrap the native function file_get_contents to add completion time and URL logging for blocking calls.  I currently override a WordPress class for doing this, but would like to take it to the next level and get closer to the metal.  In any any other language this would be easy, but PHP seems to have some limitations here.  I've looked at override_function, but am not so sure about PECL apd as I won't be able to control all the PHP installations.

The goal of the code is to simply time external HTTP calls and log them, so the system can take additional steps such as a automatically throwing in a caching reverse proxy for those calls.  I'm not looking for a full fledged profiler.

Any ideas here?  Thanks!

Comment: With so little control over the code and the server environment, I don't think it would be possible.